# Javascript Image/Text Object

Tags: javascript

I was trying to give an object an Image but I doesn`t give it back . What did I wrong ? ^^

```
var bank = {
    money:"$",
    currency:"Dollar",
    sum:50,
    src: "Logo.png"
};      

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=  " Your amount is" + bank.sum + "  "+  bank.money + "("+ bank.currency+")" + bank.src;
```

Comment: "I doesn't give it back" means what? From the code I guess you're missing an `<img>` tag for the logo ...

Comment: That object is selfish huh?  (deeply sorry i had to)

Comment: I don`t want html tags in JavaScript, It should work only with js  because I will try to programme a dynamic map where JavaScript and html are separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using an image anywhere as far as I can tell. You can't just give an "image" to javascript. You can store the URL to an image in javascript, and then you can assign this to an HTML `<img>`tag.

In html the tag would look like `<img id="testimage" src="Logo.png/>`. Then you could use javascript to change the image source. You could do it like

```
 var image = document.getElemenyById("testimage");
 image.src = bank.src;
```

Or, if you want to add an image to the body completely in Javascript, you could do that as well.

### *as you have commented on your answer, I guess this is the way you actually want to do it*

```
var img = document.createElement("img"); // creates <img>
img.src = bank.src; // sets the source to the source of the 'bank'
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(img); // adds it to the body
```

You could of course add it to your (div?) which you are using the your question.

```
 document.getElementById("test").appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the image in an `<img>` element like this:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=  " Your amount is" + bank.sum + "  "+  bank.money + "("+ bank.currency+")" + " `<img src= '"+bank.src+"' />` ";
```

Comment: You've suppressed anything related to the image... Not the solution he's looking for i beleive.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to box an object like this ?

```
var screenX1 = {
    image:"image001.png", 
    links: {
        link {
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158];
            reference to screenx2
        }
        link {
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158];
            reference to screenx3
        }
    }, 
}; 

var screenx2 = {
    ......
```

Comment: `links` is a array right? so you should put **'['** in the begin of the array and **']'** at the end, and but **','** after each one. Correcting this points it's a valid object.

Comment: Like this ?  links [
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158];
            reference to screenx2
        }
        link {
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158];
            reference to screenx3
        }
],

Comment: Like this: var screenX1 = {
    image:"image001.png", 
    links:[
        {
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158]
        },
        {
            area:[45, 143, 106, 158]
        }], 
};

Answer (score -1):

Add img tag for show image like below.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Your amount is " + bank.sum + "  "+  bank.money + " ("+ bank.currency+")" + "<img src='"+bank.src+"' />";
```

Comment: Nowhere did the OP say he was, or wanted to, use jquery. Neither is it needed for this